# can't plot rlm-object. non-NA residual length does not match cases used in fitting

Tags: r, plot, regression

I'm trying to plot a `rlm - object` but I'm getting following error

```
Error in lm.influence(x, do.coef = FALSE) : 
    non-NA residual length does not match cases used in fitting
```

I've searched for this error on the internet, but haven't found anything and I don't understand what it means and why does it appear.

The date which is used in the `rlm` regression consists out of 1 dependent variable and 4 explanatory variables. none of the observation is `NA` or `NULL`.

the result object `model$df.residual` equals `NA`. this is the only `NA` in the whole result object.

Could someone explain me how I could avoid getting the `df.residual` equal `NA`?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually in [the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/rlm.html):

> Note that the df.residual component is deliberately set to NA to avoid
>   inappropriate estimation of the residual scale from the residual mean
>   square by "lm" methods

Also a quote from the author of `MASS`

> df.residual is not a relevant concept [for rlm], and the coefficients are not 
>   t-distributed